# SEO : how to index subpages and toppage, but not pages between?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, google-index

This should be indexed :

- http://example.com/
- http://example.com/products/9823948
- http://example.com/products/3984239
- ...

but not this :

- http://example.com/products

In other words, **it is possible to automatically index the subpages, without a page to link them all** ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to prevent crawling /products in your situation would be to,

- Make no reference (Link) to /products or /products/
- If you fetch /products or /products/ return 404

Depending on your website build, Google may or may not attempt to crawl or find pages in between. If you will ensure above 2 points, you should be fine.

Comment: Yes but how would google know about (=index) the individual products pages then ? ( `http://example.com/products/3984239`) which are automatically generated ?

Comment: As well, noindex for these pages if possible would suffice. I realize not all CMS make this easy. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc I'm not sure I understand you comment right. My goal is to index `products/3984239` without having to link them from the top page, `/products` middle page wouldn't even exist in my case. How is it possible ?

Comment: That means if you can't ensure 404 on /products then its worth having noindex when the page /products loads. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en

Comment: @TopQnA Again, I don't think this is relevant : /products page doesn't exist. I just want to index the subpages but not page actually link to them

Comment: http://example.com/products/9823948 => Exists, all good. http://example.com/products => Doesn't exist then it will go to 404. You shouldn't have any issue.

Comment: @TopQnA But how google will be aware of it even if it exists, since it's not linked from anywhere ?

Comment: In most of the situation, Google shouldn't / will not attempt, and it works fine in custom sites. But when you have third-party open source CMS, you may not have linked /products from anywhere but system may give signal to attempt /products. Regardless if the page doesn't exists (404), then even if will try, it may index but it will be removed again considering 404.